# how do i store a File from Java web app in an oracle directory (not table)

Tags: java, oracle

Im looking por any kind of procedure that let me save a Java.io.file in an oracle directory, it may be a stored procedure or a java stored or somethig beyond... if somebody has any example of this, ill thank it forever. im in my web app and i need to store some uploaded files in a specific directory `/home/oracle/oracle/.../mydirectory`, almost every post is about saving to a table. **I need specifically save it to a directory**. please somebody help me!!!.

The point is i need to save an uploaded file from my web app to an oracle directory i was trying to pass the file as parameter to a stored procedure, but i dont even know what data type is compatible to pass the file as parameter ... 
ex: my_stroredprcedure(location IN VARCHAR2, theFile IN DATATYPE)...

and so on...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to save the uploaded Excel files into the Oracle directory ? Or are you trying to create files in an Oracle directory and populate them ?

Is it Excel file -> directory (accessible from Oracle) ? , or
Excel file -> Store in DB -> Create new file in Oracle directory ?

Comment: I've just added a small description of the process, i'd really apreciate if you can give me a hand, from your comment i need just get the file and store it on my oracle directory.

Comment: What exactly do you see on the filesystem when you run this?  Is the file created?  If so, what are it's contents?

Comment: im calling the stoed procedure from my ejb - app, i create a Native query and send it to the entity manager... dont know why it just doesnt do anything, if i take que generated query and paste it on the pl/sql developer sql window and execute it, it works. it creates the file, by the moment I have nothing, I´ve been also searching for examples but i couldnt find something clear enough, im not an expert i know how to do some things but im kind of desperate right now.

Comment: If the procedure runs as expected from a straight SQL environment and you're connecting as the same user as the application uses to do this test, then I suspect that you're somehow ignoring a Java exception that is thrown in your code - sorry, I'm more of an Oracle guy and now this doesn't look like an Oracle problem.

Comment: What is an "Oracle directory" ???

Comment: In Oracle a Directory is just a database object which allows us to work with an OS directory from inside the database, for instance when using UTL_FILE or external tables.  I fail to see its relevance to Java.io.file.  You need to give us more information regarding your scenario.

Comment: Did you already ask this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370433/how-do-i-write-an-uploaded-file-from-ejb3-app-to-oracle-directory

Comment: I'm guessing he's talking about java running inside Oracle, using `java.io.File` to store to Oracle's internal representation of Directory.

Comment: Check [my answer to your other question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370433/how-do-i-write-an-uploaded-file-from-ejb3-app-to-oracle-directory/1382057#1382057).

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have explained yourself it is apparent that your real question is how to transfer a file from the client to the server.  The solution to this is `ftp`.

If you want to call `ftp` from within the database there are a number of possible ways of doing it.  Tim Hall covers this topic on his [Oracle-Base site](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:ovgsKum4UQoJ:www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/FTPFromPLSQL.php+pl/sql+ftp&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk).  He has written an `ftp` implementation in PL/SQL: get the [package spec](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/ftp.pks) and [package body](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/miscellaneous/ftp.pkb).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't necessarily need to use Oracle libraries to store the file. You would query the location of the Oracle Directory from the data dictionary (if you need to), i.e.

`SELECT directory_name
 FROM user_directories;`

Then you would use standard Java IO libraries to write the file to that directory, assuming you have access to it, and remembering that the path is relevant to the database server.

What kind of file do you want to store? Is there any need to use the DBMS for this task at all? You can use UTL_FILE to write to an Oracle directory from a stored procedure if you need to.

In order to properly answer your question, we need to know a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont get it, from my web app, i´ll execute the query you told me above, and what do i expect to recieve a path? and later in mi class instance a new File x = new File(path_returned_from_query)?? sorry i don´t know more than the basics. If you don´t mind will you explain it with an example.

Comment: Okay, if you are writing to a file to a directory, why do you need to use the Oracle Database to do this? The query I gave would return the path of the Oracle Directory object. For example: The path to an Oracle Directory with the name "AUDIT_DIR" could be returned with:

SELECT directory_path
FROM all_directories
WHERE directory_name = 'AUDIT_DIR';

The reason I ask: This is a much more trivial task to perform using straight Java. If you need to use Oracle, you should google Oracle BLOBs (binary large objects), which JDBC drivers support- I couldn't provide an example off the top of my head.